# How to read csv file for text mining

Tags: r, csv, text-mining

I will be using `tm` for text mining purpose.However, my file CSV file is weired .Below is the `dput`,after I used `read.table`  function in r. There are three column lie, sentiment and review. However the fourth coulmn contain review with no column name.I am New to R and Text mining. If I use `read.csv`it is getting me an error. Please suggest better approach for reading csv file.

**Update:**

```
  > dput(head(df))

structure(list(V1 = c("lie,sentiment,review", "f,n,'Mike\\'s", 
"f,n,'i", "f,n,'After", "f,n,'Olive", "f,n,'I"), V2 = c("", "Pizza", 
"really", "I", "Oil", "went"), V3 = c("", "High", "like", "went", 
"Garden", "to"), V4 = c("", "Point,", "this", "shopping", "was", 
"the"), V5 = c("", "NY", "buffet", "with", "very", "Chilis"), 
    V6 = c("", "Service", "restaurant", "some", "disappointing.", 
    "on"), V7 = c("", "was", "in", "of", "I", "Erie"), V8 = c("", 
    "very", "Marshall", "my", "expect", "Blvd"), V9 = c("", "slow", 
    "street.", "friend,", "good", "and"), V10 = c("", "and", 
    "they", "we", "food", "had"), V11 = c("", "the", "have", 
    "went", "and", "the"), V12 = c("", "quality", "a", "to", 
    "good", "worst"), V13 = c("", "was", "lot", "DODO", "service", 
    "meal"), V14 = c("", "low.", "of", "restaurant", "(at", "of"
    ), V15 = c("", "You", "selection", "for", "least!!)", "my"
    ), V16 = c("", "would", "of", "dinner.", "when", "life."), 
    V17 = c("", "think", "american,", "I", "I", "We"), V18 = c("", 
    "they", "japanese,", "found", "go", "arrived"), V19 = c("", 
    "would", "and", "worm", "out", "and"), V20 = c("", "know", 
    "chinese", "in", "to", "waited"), V21 = c("", "at", "dishes.", 
    "one", "eat.", "5"), V22 = c("", "least", "we", "of", "The", 
    "minutes"), V23 = c("", "how", "also", "the", "meal", "for"
    ), V24 = c("", "to", "got", "dishes", "was", "a"), V25 = c("", 
    "make", "a", ".'", "cold", "hostess,"), V26 = c("", "good", 
    "free", "", "when", "and"), V27 = c("", "pizza,", "drink", 
    "", "we", "then"), V28 = c("", "not.", "and", "", "got", 
    "were"), V29 = c("", "Stick", "free", "", "it,", "seated"
    ), V30 = c("", "to", "refill.", "", "and", "by"), V31 = c("", 
    "pre-made", "there", "", "the", "a"), V32 = c("", "dishes", 
    "are", "", "waitor", "waiter"), V33 = c("", "like", "also", 
    "", "had", "who"), V34 = c("", "stuffed", "different", "", 
    "no", "was"), V35 = c("", "pasta", "kinds", "", "manners", 
    "obviously"), V36 = c("", "or", "of", "", "whatsoever.", 
    "in"), V37 = c("", "a", "dessert.", "", "Don\\'t", "a"), 
    V38 = c("", "salad.", "the", "", "go", "terrible"), V39 = c("", 
    "You", "staff", "", "to", "mood."), V40 = c("", "should", 
    "is", "", "the", "We"), V41 = c("", "consider", "very", "", 
    "Olive", "order"), V42 = c("", "dining", "friendly.", "", 
    "Oil", "drinks"), V43 = c("", "else", "it", "", "Garden.", 
    "and"), V44 = c("", "where.'", "is", "", "\nf,n,", "it"), 
    V45 = c("", "", "also", "", "The", "took"), V46 = c("", "", 
    "quite", "", "Seven", "them"), V47 = c("", "", "cheap", "", 
    "Heaven", "15"), V48 = c("", "", "compared", "", "restaurant", 
    "minutes"), V49 = c("", "", "with", "", "was", "to"), V50 = c("", 
    "", "the", "", "never", "bring"), V51 = c("", "", "other", 
    "", "known", "us"), V52 = c("", "", "restaurant", "", "for", 
    "both"), V53 = c("", "", "in", "", "a", "the"), V54 = c("", 
    "", "syracuse", "", "superior", "wrong"), V55 = c("", "", 
    "area.", "", "service", "beers"), V56 = c("", "", "i", "", 
    "but", "which"), V57 = c("", "", "will", "", "what", "were"
    ), V58 = c("", "", "definitely", "", "we", "barely"), V59 = c("", 
    "", "coming", "", "experienced", "cold."), V60 = c("", "", 
    "back", "", "last", "Then"), V61 = c("", "", "here.'", "", 
    "week", "we"), V62 = c("", "", "", "", "was", "order"), V63 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "a", "an"), V64 = c("", "", "", "", "disaster.", 
    "appetizer"), V65 = c("", "", "", "", "The", "and"), V66 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "waiter", "wait"), V67 = c("", "", "", "", "would", 
    "25"), V68 = c("", "", "", "", "not", "minutes"), V69 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "notice", "for"), V70 = c("", "", "", "", "us", 
    "cold"), V71 = c("", "", "", "", "until", "southwest"), V72 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "we", "egg"), V73 = c("", "", "", "", "asked", 
    "rolls,"), V74 = c("", "", "", "", "him", "at"), V75 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "4", "which"), V76 = c("", "", "", "", "times", 
    "point"), V77 = c("", "", "", "", "to", "we"), V78 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "bring", "just"), V79 = c("", "", "", "", "us", 
    "paid"), V80 = c("", "", "", "", "the", "and"), V81 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "menu.", "left."), V82 = c("", "", "", "", "The", 
    "Don\\'t"), V83 = c("", "", "", "", "food", "go.'"), V84 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "was", ""), V85 = c("", "", "", "", "not", ""
    ), V86 = c("", "", "", "", "exceptional", ""), V87 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "either.", ""), V88 = c("", "", "", "", "It", 
    ""), V89 = c("", "", "", "", "took", ""), V90 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "them", ""), V91 = c("", "", "", "", "though", ""
    ), V92 = c("", "", "", "", "2", ""), V93 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "minutes", ""), V94 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), V95 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "bring", ""), V96 = c("", "", "", "", "us", ""
    ), V97 = c("", "", "", "", "a", ""), V98 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "check", ""), V99 = c("", "", "", "", "after", ""), V100 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "they", ""), V101 = c("", "", "", "", "spotted", 
    ""), V102 = c("", "", "", "", "we", ""), V103 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "finished", ""), V104 = c("", "", "", "", "eating", 
    ""), V105 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), V106 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "are", ""), V107 = c("", "", "", "", "not", ""), 
    V108 = c("", "", "", "", "ordering", ""), V109 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "more.", ""), V110 = c("", "", "", "", "Well,", ""
    ), V111 = c("", "", "", "", "never", ""), V112 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "more.", ""), V113 = c("", "", "", "", "\nf,n,", 
    ""), V114 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V115 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "went", ""), V116 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), 
    V117 = c("", "", "", "", "XYZ", ""), V118 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "restaurant", ""), V119 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""
    ), V120 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), V121 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "a", ""), V122 = c("", "", "", "", "terrible", ""
    ), V123 = c("", "", "", "", "experience.", ""), V124 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "I", ""), V125 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), 
    V126 = c("", "", "", "", "a", ""), V127 = c("", "", "", "", 
    "YELP", ""), V128 = c("", "", "", "", "Free", ""), V129 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "Appetizer", ""), V130 = c("", "", "", "", "coupon", 
    ""), V131 = c("", "", "", "", "which", ""), V132 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "could", ""), V133 = c("", "", "", "", "be", 
    ""), V134 = c("", "", "", "", "applied", ""), V135 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "upon", ""), V136 = c("", "", "", "", "checking", 
    ""), V137 = c("", "", "", "", "in", ""), V138 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "to", ""), V139 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V140 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "restaurant.", ""), V141 = c("", "", "", "", 
    "The", ""), V142 = c("", "", "", "", "person", ""), V143 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "serving", ""), V144 = c("", "", "", "", "us", 
    ""), V145 = c("", "", "", "", "was", ""), V146 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "very", ""), V147 = c("", "", "", "", "rude", ""), 
    V148 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), V149 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "didn\\'t", ""), V150 = c("", "", "", "", "acknowledge", 
    ""), V151 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V152 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "coupon.", ""), V153 = c("", "", "", "", "When", 
    ""), V154 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V155 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "asked", ""), V156 = c("", "", "", "", "her", ""), 
    V157 = c("", "", "", "", "about", ""), V158 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "it,", ""), V159 = c("", "", "", "", "she", ""), V160 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "rudely", ""), V161 = c("", "", "", "", "replied", 
    ""), V162 = c("", "", "", "", "back", ""), V163 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "saying", ""), V164 = c("", "", "", "", "she", ""
    ), V165 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), V166 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "already", ""), V167 = c("", "", "", "", "applied", 
    ""), V168 = c("", "", "", "", "it.", ""), V169 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "Then", ""), V170 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V171 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "inquired", ""), V172 = c("", "", "", "", "about", 
    ""), V173 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V174 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "free", ""), V175 = c("", "", "", "", "salad", ""
    ), V176 = c("", "", "", "", "that", ""), V177 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "they", ""), V178 = c("", "", "", "", "serve.", ""
    ), V179 = c("", "", "", "", "She", ""), V180 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "rudely", ""), V181 = c("", "", "", "", "said", ""
    ), V182 = c("", "", "", "", "that", ""), V183 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "you", ""), V184 = c("", "", "", "", "have", ""), 
    V185 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), V186 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "order", ""), V187 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V188 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "main", ""), V189 = c("", "", "", "", "course", 
    ""), V190 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), V191 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "get", ""), V192 = c("", "", "", "", "that.", ""), 
    V193 = c("", "", "", "", "Overall,", ""), V194 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "I", ""), V195 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), V196 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "a", ""), V197 = c("", "", "", "", "bad", ""), 
    V198 = c("", "", "", "", "experience", ""), V199 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "as", ""), V200 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), 
    V201 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), V202 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "taken", ""), V203 = c("", "", "", "", "my", ""), V204 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "family", ""), V205 = c("", "", "", "", "to", 
    ""), V206 = c("", "", "", "", "that", ""), V207 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "restaurant", ""), V208 = c("", "", "", "", "for", 
    ""), V209 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V210 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "first", ""), V211 = c("", "", "", "", "time", ""
    ), V212 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), V213 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "I", ""), V214 = c("", "", "", "", "had", ""), V215 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "high", ""), V216 = c("", "", "", "", "hopes", 
    ""), V217 = c("", "", "", "", "from", ""), V218 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "the", ""), V219 = c("", "", "", "", "restaurant", 
    ""), V220 = c("", "", "", "", "which", ""), V221 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "is,", ""), V222 = c("", "", "", "", "otherwise,", 
    ""), V223 = c("", "", "", "", "my", ""), V224 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "favorite", ""), V225 = c("", "", "", "", "place", 
    ""), V226 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), V227 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "dine.", ""), V228 = c("", "", "", "", "\nf,n,", 
    ""), V229 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V230 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "went", ""), V231 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), 
    V232 = c("", "", "", "", "ABC", ""), V233 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "restaurant", ""), V234 = c("", "", "", "", "two", ""
    ), V235 = c("", "", "", "", "days", ""), V236 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "ago", ""), V237 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), 
    V238 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V239 = c("", "", "", "", 
    "hated", ""), V240 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V241 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "food", ""), V242 = c("", "", "", "", "and", 
    ""), V243 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V244 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "service.", ""), V245 = c("", "", "", "", "We", ""
    ), V246 = c("", "", "", "", "were", ""), V247 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "kept", ""), V248 = c("", "", "", "", "waiting", 
    ""), V249 = c("", "", "", "", "for", ""), V250 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "over", ""), V251 = c("", "", "", "", "an", ""), 
    V252 = c("", "", "", "", "hour", ""), V253 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "just", ""), V254 = c("", "", "", "", "to", ""), V255 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "get", ""), V256 = c("", "", "", "", "seated", 
    ""), V257 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), V258 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "once", ""), V259 = c("", "", "", "", "we", ""), 
    V260 = c("", "", "", "", "ordered,", ""), V261 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "our", ""), V262 = c("", "", "", "", "food", ""), 
    V263 = c("", "", "", "", "came", ""), V264 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "out", ""), V265 = c("", "", "", "", "cold.", ""), V266 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "I", ""), V267 = c("", "", "", "", "ordered", 
    ""), V268 = c("", "", "", "", "the", ""), V269 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "pasta", ""), V270 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), 
    V271 = c("", "", "", "", "it", ""), V272 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "was", ""), V273 = c("", "", "", "", "terrible", ""), 
    V274 = c("", "", "", "", "-", ""), V275 = c("", "", "", "", 
    "completely", ""), V276 = c("", "", "", "", "bland", ""), 
    V277 = c("", "", "", "", "and", ""), V278 = c("", "", "", 
    "", "very", ""), V279 = c("", "", "", "", "unappatizing.", 
    ""), V280 = c("", "", "", "", "I", ""), V281 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "definitely", ""), V282 = c("", "", "", "", "would", 
    ""), V283 = c("", "", "", "", "not", ""), V284 = c("", "", 
    "", "", "recommend", ""), V285 = c("", "", "", "", "going", 
    ""), V286 = c("", "", "", "", "there,", ""), V287 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "especially", ""), V288 = c("", "", "", "", "if", 
    ""), V289 = c("", "", "", "", "you\\'re", ""), V290 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "in", ""), V291 = c("", "", "", "", "a", ""), 
    V292 = c("", "", "", "", "hurry!'", "")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", 
"V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29", 
"V30", "V31", "V32", "V33", "V34", "V35", "V36", "V37", "V38", 
"V39", "V40", "V41", "V42", "V43", "V44", "V45", "V46", "V47", 
"V48", "V49", "V50", "V51", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V55", "V56", 
"V57", "V58", "V59", "V60", "V61", "V62", "V63", "V64", "V65", 
"V66", "V67", "V68", "V69", "V70", "V71", "V72", "V73", "V74", 
"V75", "V76", "V77", "V78", "V79", "V80", "V81", "V82", "V83", 
"V84", "V85", "V86", "V87", "V88", "V89", "V90", "V91", "V92", 
"V93", "V94", "V95", "V96", "V97", "V98", "V99", "V100", "V101", 
"V102", "V103", "V104", "V105", "V106", "V107", "V108", "V109", 
"V110", "V111", "V112", "V113", "V114", "V115", "V116", "V117", 
"V118", "V119", "V120", "V121", "V122", "V123", "V124", "V125", 
"V126", "V127", "V128", "V129", "V130", "V131", "V132", "V133", 
"V134", "V135", "V136", "V137", "V138", "V139", "V140", "V141", 
"V142", "V143", "V144", "V145", "V146", "V147", "V148", "V149", 
"V150", "V151", "V152", "V153", "V154", "V155", "V156", "V157", 
"V158", "V159", "V160", "V161", "V162", "V163", "V164", "V165", 
"V166", "V167", "V168", "V169", "V170", "V171", "V172", "V173", 
"V174", "V175", "V176", "V177", "V178", "V179", "V180", "V181", 
"V182", "V183", "V184", "V185", "V186", "V187", "V188", "V189", 
"V190", "V191", "V192", "V193", "V194", "V195", "V196", "V197", 
"V198", "V199", "V200", "V201", "V202", "V203", "V204", "V205", 
"V206", "V207", "V208", "V209", "V210", "V211", "V212", "V213", 
"V214", "V215", "V216", "V217", "V218", "V219", "V220", "V221", 
"V222", "V223", "V224", "V225", "V226", "V227", "V228", "V229", 
"V230", "V231", "V232", "V233", "V234", "V235", "V236", "V237", 
"V238", "V239", "V240", "V241", "V242", "V243", "V244", "V245", 
"V246", "V247", "V248", "V249", "V250", "V251", "V252", "V253", 
"V254", "V255", "V256", "V257", "V258", "V259", "V260", "V261", 
"V262", "V263", "V264", "V265", "V266", "V267", "V268", "V269", 
"V270", "V271", "V272", "V273", "V274", "V275", "V276", "V277", 
"V278", "V279", "V280", "V281", "V282", "V283", "V284", "V285", 
"V286", "V287", "V288", "V289", "V290", "V291", "V292"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Dataset**:

```
lie sentiment   review                                                                                  
f   n   'Mike\'s Pizza High Point    NY Service was very slow and the quality was low. You would think they would know at least how to make good pizza   not. Stick to pre-made dishes like stuffed pasta or a salad. You should consider dining else where.'                                                                           
f   n   'i really like this buffet restaurant in Marshall street. they have a lot of selection of american   japanese    and chinese dishes. we also got a free drink and free refill. there are also different kinds of dessert. the staff is very friendly. it is also quite cheap compared with the other restaurant in syracuse area. i will definitely coming back here.'                                                                          
f   n   'After I went shopping with some of my friend    we went to DODO restaurant for dinner. I found worm in one of the dishes .'                                                                                
f   n   'Olive Oil Garden was very disappointing. I expect good food and good service (at least!!) when I go out to eat. The meal was cold when we got it    and the waitor had no manners whatsoever. Don\'t go to the Olive Oil Garden. '                                                                             
f   n   'The Seven Heaven restaurant was never known for a superior service but what we experienced last week was a disaster. The waiter would not notice us until we asked him 4 times to bring us the menu. The food was not exceptional either. It took them though 2 minutes to bring us a check after they spotted we finished eating and are not ordering more. Well   never more. '                                                                              
f   n   'I went to XYZ restaurant and had a terrible experience. I had a YELP Free Appetizer coupon which could be applied upon checking in to the restaurant. The person serving us was very rude and didn\'t acknowledge the coupon. When I asked her about it     she rudely replied back saying she had already applied it. Then I inquired about the free salad that they serve. She rudely said that you have to order the main course to get that. Overall    I had a bad experience as I had taken my family to that restaurant for the first time and I had high hopes from the restaurant which is     otherwise   my favorite place to dine. '                                                                   
f   n   'I went to ABC restaurant two days ago and I hated the food and the service. We were kept waiting for over an hour just to get seated and once we ordered    our food came out cold. I ordered the pasta and it was terrible - completely bland and very unappatizing. I definitely would not recommend going there  especially if you\'re in a hurry!'                                                                         
f   n   'I went to the Chilis on Erie Blvd and had the worst meal of my life. We arrived and waited 5 minutes for a hostess  and then were seated by a waiter who was obviously in a terrible mood. We order drinks and it took them 15 minutes to bring us both the wrong beers which were barely cold. Then we order an appetizer and wait 25 minutes for cold southwest egg rolls     at which point we just paid and left. Don\'t go.'                                                                          
f   n   'OMG. This restaurant is horrible. The receptionist did not greet us     we just stood there and waited for five minutes. The food came late and served not warm. Me and my pet ordered a bowl of salad and a cheese pizza. The salad was not fresh  the crust of a pizza was so hard like plastics. My dog didn\'t even eat that pizza. I hate this place!!!!!!!!!!'
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please include a subset of your data using `dput()` rather than a download link. There are a few useful techniques for reading in odd or poorly shaped data files, but I can't know for sure which will help you without an example, but I'm not going to blindly download from a link.

Comment: @DanHall. Thanks for reply! above please see dput() of the dataset

Comment: Ok, so that's what you get. Now, try pasting in the first few (maybe 6-10) lines of the csv file, also in code brackets.

Comment: @DanHall. Done!

Comment: Maybe `library(readr); df <- read_csv("deception.csv", quote = "'")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you removed the file from the original post, @Yes Boss but this answer is based on this file, rather than your `dput` output. The file basically had two problems why you couldn't read it in. 1. Your quote character was `'` instead of the more common `"`; 2. `'` is also used in the column `review` which is a bit too much for base (it tries to split into new columns in these instances). Luckily, the package data.table is a bit smarter and can take care of problem #2:

```
library(data.table)

df <- fread(file = "deception.csv", quote="\'")
```

The resulting object will be a data.table instead of a data.frame:

```
> str(df)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  92 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ lie      : chr  "f" "f" "f" "f" ...
 $ sentiment: chr  "n" "n" "n" "n" ...
 $ review   : chr  "Mike\\'s Pizza High Point, NY Service was very slow and the quality was low. You would think they would know at"| __truncated__ "i really like this buffet restaurant in Marshall street. they have a lot of selection of american, japanese, an"| __truncated__ "After I went shopping with some of my friend, we went to DODO restaurant for dinner. I found worm in one of the dishes ." "Olive Oil Garden was very disappointing. I expect good food and good service (at least!!) when I go out to eat."| __truncated__ ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

You can turn this behaviour off by setting `data.table = FALSE` in `fread()` (if you want to, I recommend learning how to work with data.table).

A personal opinionated note: If you want to get into text mining, look into the quanteda package instead of tm. It is a lot faster and has a more modern approach to many tasks.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like chram. Will definitely look into quanteda package

Answer (score 0):

For this particular text file, you need to look at the `quote` argument. In `read.table()`, the default `quote` argument is either a single or double quote. Here you need to make it just a single quote:

```
df <- read.table("filename", header = TRUE, quote = "\'")

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ lie      : Factor w/ 1 level "f": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  $ sentiment: Factor w/ 1 level "n": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  $ review   : Factor w/ 9 levels "After I went shopping with some of my friend    we went to DODO restaurant for dinner. I found worm in one of the dishes .",..: 6 2 1 7 9 5 3 4 8
```

That should do it for you.

I'd recommend reading the help file for `read.table()` (all the way through). There's a lot to consider.

Comment: Dan. I tried above code and it is giving me an error saying :error in read.table ("filename",header=T,quote=" ' ") More columns than column names. Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Comment: it looks like @JonGrub was braver than me and downloaded the file from your link.

Comment: I tried it with the original file (the link was in the original post but was removed) and the problem is that there are ´'´ characters inside the text column as well.

Comment: @JonGrub if they aren't escaped, then, yes, that would be a problem. In the subset of the file (the header and the first 9 lines of data) all the `'` characters are escaped, so we don't run into that problem.

Comment: Thanks for explaining guys! now I better understood the concept of reading csv file especially files that contains '

Comment: @DanHall, I guess so. I din't go through the whole file but actually tried the quote character first and it gave me `more columns than column names` error consistently which is usually a sign for unescaped quote characters